# ncurses: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer

Tags: c, gcc, ncurses

I am trying to understand the NCURSES source code and struck at the error point. The code is as following:

```
#include<stdio.h>


struct screen {
    void *_current_attr;
};

typedef struct screen SCREEN;

SCREEN * SP = ((void *)0);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ((*(SP)->_current_attr)) = (
                                ((*((SP)->_current_attr))) & 
                                ~((~(1UL - 1UL)) << ((0) + 8))) | ((1UL - 1UL)
                                );
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error messages as:

```
In function ‘main’:
warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
error: invalid use of void expression
```

I want to know what is the reason for the error and solution for it?

Comment: What line does the error occur on? The first line of `main`, I assume?

Comment: error on line no 13, 14, 15, 16

Comment: That's all four lines of the assignment statement inside `main`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
*((SP)->_current_attr))
```

This is equivalent (as far as I can tell) to

```
*(SP->_current_attr)
```

Since `_current_attr` is of type `void*`, a `void*` is being dereferenced, which is illegal.

One way you could solve this problem is by giving a type to `_current_attr`.

```
struct screen {
  int *_current_attr;
};
```

Comment: Well, the problem could be solved by removing the content of `main`. I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't "solve" the error unless you explain what `main` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The _current_attr pointer has been declared void*. Before accessing/dereferncing this pointer you need to type cast,so that it points to relevant type which you are expecting in this pointer.

Comment: It's usually better to define the pointer so it's of the expected type in the first place. Casting a `void*` make sense only if you're potentially going to be pointing to different types at different places in your code.

Comment: Before dereferencing a void *pointer, type cast it to the required type. But you need to define this "Required Type". By looking at your code line                                                      ((*(SP)->_current_attr)) = (((*((SP)->_current_attr))) & 
                   ~((~(1UL - 1UL)) << ((0) + 8))) | ((1UL - 1UL));
I think unsigned long * pointer would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly what's wrong: you're dereferencing a void pointer. You have to tell the compiler what kinds of things a pointer is pointing to before trying to fetch them. `void *` is just way of saying "I'll tell you at runtime". `SP` points to a `struct screen`, so it should be declared a `struct screen *`. The member `_current_atrr`, well, I can't tell what it's supposed to point to. You're doing math with it, so maybe it's supposed to be an `int *`?  But then, you'll also need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: how to allocate memory to it

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. I can't write your code for you, only you know what you're trying to do.

Comment: The `typedef` causes SP to be declared as a `struct screen` doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, so it does. I guess it's only complaining about `_current_attr` then.